# Clonar base de datos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estaba clonando una base de datos en `MySQL` mediante el siguiente comando:

```
$user@host: mysqldump -u root -p MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -u root -p MyDatabaseCopy
```

Y el *output* fue el siguiente:

> Enter password: Enter password:

Ingresé la contraseña y se quedó en la ejecución de este sin detenerse o mostrar un resultado, **sin embargo**, me generó la *copia* correctamente
por lo que terminé cancelando la ejecución con una interrupción mediante el teclado (*ctrl + c*)

Intenté hacer otra copia con el mismo comando tan solo cambiando el nombre de la copia:

```
$user@host: mysqldump -u root -p MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -u root -p MyDatabaseCopy2
```

Sin embargo me generó el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'MyDatabaseCopy2'

**Nunca terminó la ejecución y tampoco me copió correctamente la base de datos.**

- ¿Por qué funcionó correctamente la primera vez y luego no?
- ¿Por qué nunca terminó la ejecución en ambos casos?
- **¿Cual es la forma más óptima y recomendada para clonar una base de
  datos en `MySQL`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un punto importante es que, como estás usando un *pipeline*, puede no ser posible leer de `STDIN` la contraseña al servidor. Puedes incluirla directamente en la llamada al comando:

```sh
$ mysql -u root -pTuPassword
```

**Importante:** No hay espacios entre la opción `-p` y la contraseña. Puedes hacer lo mismo en la opción `-p` de `mysqldump`.

Si deseas clonar la base de datos en el mismo servidor del que la estás extrayendo, debes crear previamente la base de datos de destino.

En la CLI de MySQL:

```sql
mysql> create database MyDatabaseCopy;
```

Una vez creada la base de datos, puedes ejecutar `mysqldump`:

```sh
$ mysqldump -u root -pTuPassword MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -u root -pTuPassword MyDatabaseCopy
```

Si vas a clonar tu base de datos en otro servidor, entonces puedes usar el *pipeline*; sólo asegúrate de incluir la opción `--DATABASES` en la llamada a `mysqldump`:

```sh
$ mysqldump -h hostOrigen -u root -pTuPassword --databases MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -h hostDestino -u root -pTuPassword
```

**Importante:** Si haces esto, el nombre de la base de datos en el host de destino será igual que en el host de origen.

Si quieres probar que el comando funciona correctamente, pero no quieres esperar a que se haga el dump de toda la base de datos, puedes usar la opción `--no-data` (o `-d`) para crear un dump que contenga sólo la estructura, sin incluir los datos de cada tabla:

```sh
$mysqldump -h hostOrigen -u root -pTuPassword -d --databases MyOriginalDatabase > pruebaDump.sql
```

---

[Recuerda incluir las opciones pertinentes al ejecutar `mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary). Por ejemplo, si la base de datos tiene procedimientos o funciones almacenados, debes agregar la opción `-R` para que estos se incluyan en el dump.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quedo en blanco era porque estaba clonando, dependiendo del tamaño de la base de datos que quieras clonar es el tiempo que tardara en realizar el proceso.

Cuando quisiste clonarla por segunda ves, no existia una base de datos a la cual clonar, por eso te indica un error al no encontrar la base de datos "MyDatabaseCopy2".... antes de poder clonarla, debes crear la base de datos para posteriormente clonarla con exito....

Hay diferentes maneras que te pueden funcionar bien, mira, te paso unos pasos para realizar el proceso que deseas... (Lo obtuve de una fuente de internet)

Lo primero que debemos hacer es realizar un volcado de la base de datos a un fichero:

```
mysqldump -u nombre_usuario -p nombre_base_datos > nombre_fichero_volcado
```

Lo segundo será iniciar sesión en el servidor MySQL con nuestro cliente:

```
mysql -u nombre_usuario -p
```

Dentro del servidor creamos la base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE nombre_base_datos_copia;
```

Salimos del cliente:

```
exit
```

Ya podemos copiar el volcado a la base de datos recién creada:

```
mysql -u nombre_usuario -p nombre_base-datos_copia < volcado
```