# ¿Cómo reemplazo $ en comandos de MySQL en terminal Unix para realizar las mismas acciones en workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Buen día, quiero clonar una base de datos pero resulta que tengo el inconveniente de que está acción involucra comandos que desconozco como:

```sql
$ mysql -u root -pTuPassword

mysql> create database MyDatabaseCopy;

$ mysqldump -u root -pTuPassword MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -u root -pTuPassword MyDatabaseC

$ mysqldump -h hostOrigen -u root -pTuPassword --databases MyOriginalDatabase | mysql -h hostDestino -u root -pTuPassword
```

**Y aquí es donde me pierdo porqué al parecer usan la terminal, pero si yo uso workbench no lo puedo hacer? Como serian los comandos en workbench para poder clonar una base de datos (por ejemplo) bd_clinica a una nueva que quiero llamar bd_max.**

Esos "$" siguen siendo comandos mysql o como es el cuento?

Muchas gracias

Los comandos extraidos vienen del siguiente enlace: [Clonar base de datos en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44345/clonar-base-de-datos-en-mysql)

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Te refieres al [prompt en la terminal?](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt)

Comment: Exacto, ya estoy leyendo el término, ahora no sé si en el post anterior estaban hablando de sistemas Unix o Windows, yo uso es Windows...

Comment: si usas windows, solo necesitas omitir el `$` y copiar el comando, eso solo hace referencia a una terminal

Comment: pero workbench tiene utilidades para hacer esto dentro de si mismo... tengo mis dudas de si esta pregunta termina siendo valida (ya que el $ no tiene nada que ver mysql)

Comment: Teóricamente si es válida porque si hace parte de los comandos pero con un énfasis en terminales (lo cual no tenía claro y fue aclarado gracias a tu respuesta) pero más abajo hago la salvedad de que si efectivamente era terminal, como lo hago en workbench? :(

Comment: No. no son parte de los comandos.. si los corrieras sobre windows verias otro prompt. a eso me refiero, el comando empieza por mysqldump .. lo de adelante.. no tiene nada que ver.. y hasta podria ser otra cosa.. Para lo otro, lee el manual de workbench...

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta en este caso el signo de pesos $, representa al Prompot en linux.

Se llama prompt al carácter o conjunto de caracteres que se muestran en una línea de comandos para indicar que está a la espera de órdenes. Este puede variar dependiendo del intérprete de comandos y suele ser configurable.

Si usas workbench no debes preocuparte por ese caracter.